# Fatal Error: [] Operator not working on one page but working on another

Tags: php, html, mysql

My code says I get the following error: `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in`

The problem is, I use the same code on the members page, but when I include it on my albums page, it gives me the error. The PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, song_genres.genre FROM favoriteband JOIN song_genres ON favoriteband.band_name = song_genres.band_name WHERE favoriteband.username = '$username'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); #query

# If user has not favorited bands
$rows_returned = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($rows_returned < 1) { ?>

    <tr>
        <th>For Recommendations,<br> Start Liking Bands</th>
    </tr>

<?php } else {

# Loop through each song
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $username = $row['username'];               # Loop Username
    $band_name[] = $row['band_name'];       # Get the Band Name
    $genre[] = $row['genre'];               # Get the Genres for each band
}

// The error is fond on $band_name[] = $row['band_name'];
// Also $rows_returned shows 77 rows, so it does produce multiple values.
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
<!-- MEMBER RECOMMENDATIONS -->
<table style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr >
        <th style="background: green; color: #fff;" colspan="2">My Recommendations</th>
    </tr>
    <?php include ("process/memberRecommendation.php"); ?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

It works on the member page, but not the album page. It baffles me, because if it works once, it should always work the same.

Comment: you need to declare $band_name=array();   and $genre = array();

Comment: It worked! Thank you. But the underlying question. How did it work on one page without me calling `$band_name = array();`, but not the other. That seems mystically odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$band_name = $row['band_name']; //works
$genre = $row['genre'];   //works
```

Then if you treat string like an array it will give that fatal error:

```
$bandname[] = 'string'; // fatal error
```

just add this in the beginning to fix that error

```
$band_name = array();
$genre = array();
```